# How to override natural navigation in c# winforms

Tags: c#, winforms

**Domain understanding**
I'm making an application for dentists and at one point I have to show the teeth of the patient and allow the dentist to register information about several points around each tooth.
To make the application dynamic I create the teeth depending on the patient (some have more or fewer teeth).
So the mouth has a number of teeth and depending on the settings each tooth has a number of measurement points.
The dentists register the points in different orders depending on preference (set in settings). Some register all points on a tooth and then move to the next, others register all points along the front of all teeth and then all the points along the back of the teeth.

**The issue**
As I create each tooth and add the measurement points to it, the natural tab order is: all the points on one tooth, move to next tooth [repeat].
I need to control this in a different way.

I need to be able to navigate (tab) to a control in another usercontrol and then return later for the rest of the points.

Both tab and the arrow keys cause navigation, so I have to deal with both (well all navigation, but these are the ones I've discovered to far)

**Trial and error**
I tried to override OnKeyUp/Down/Press and handle the events for the key press, but to no avail.
In stead I get a double effect; both my navigation AND the natural navigation.

What is the smartest and easiest way to be in complete control of the navigation?

Answer (score 0):

For Tab there is a ContainerControl function called ProcessTabKey. This is where the natural navigation for Tab happens. If you override this you can provide our own navigation: (or just return true and do it somewhere else)

```
protected override bool ProcessTabKey(bool forward)
{
    return forward ? this.NextPoint() : this.PreviousPoint();
}
```

As for the arrow-navigation, I've found that to be a little trickier. There are a number of overridable functions that register key presses.
I think the best one is [ProcessCmdKey](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.processcmdkey(v=vs.85).aspx). This function must return "true if the character was processed by the control; otherwise, false":

```
    protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
    {
        if (keyData == Keys.Right)
        {
            this.NextField();
            return true;
        }
        if (keyData == Keys.Left)
        {
            this.PreviousField();
            return true;
        }
        if (keyData == Keys.Down) return true;
        if (keyData == Keys.Up) return true;
        return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
    }
```

This will cause my own navigation to happen and let the framework know 'I already dealt with this' (or I could just return true and handle it somewhere else). Any other 'command' keys can be handled the same (like Tab), however this does not handle the modifiers!

Both Tab and the Arrow keys navigate if Shift is pressed. If I want to handle all my navigation here it should look something like this:

```
    protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
    {
        switch (keyData)
        {
            case Keys.Right:
            case Keys.Right|Keys.Shift:
            case Keys.Enter:
                // move to next field
                this.NextField();
                return true;
            case Keys.Left:
            case Keys.Left|Keys.Shift:
                // move to previous field
                this.PreviousField();
                return true;
            case Keys.Down:
            case Keys.Down|Keys.Shift:
            case Keys.Up:
            case Keys.Up|Keys.Shift:
                // disable native navigation
                return true;
            case Keys.Tab:
                // move to next point
                return this.NextPoint();
            case Keys.Tab|Keys.Shift:
                // move to previous point
                return this.PreviousPoint();
        }
        return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
    }
```

Handling Tab in ProcessCmdKey negates the need to override ProcessTabKey .

Comment: _[Etiquette for answering your own question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17845/etiquette-for-answering-your-own-question)_